# Использование многомерных массивов в v-for. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Если в атрибутиве v-for указать "post in posts" то все нормально, все выводит. Но если указать "post.coment in post.coments" то выводит ошибку

Comment: Дайте более развернутый вопрос, какая у вас ошибка (добавьте ее текст в ответ), какие данные вы туда вставляете (что из себя представляет posts), добавьте html, где видно, как вы это вставляете.

Answer (score 1):

Надо создавать переменную так

`comment in post.coments`.

Ошибка возникает потому, что вы хотите создать переменную `post.coment`, но такое невозможно сделать в данном примере.